# Adding new XML nodes to mixed content

Tags: c#, xml

I want to add new nodes to an XML file that has a schema that looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Building>
   <Street>Wood street
      <Number>3
         <Flats>1</Flats>
      </Number>
   </Street> 
</Building>
```

I want to add a new building (e.g., Wood street 5 with 8 flats).  If the street already exists, it should add a new child to the existing street.

So the schema would look like this if it existed:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Building>
   <Street>Wood street
      <Number>3
         <Flats>1</Flats>
      </Number>
      <Number>5
         <Flats>8</Flats>
      </Number>
   </Street> 
</Building>
```

and if it didn't exist:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Building>
   <Street>Wood street
      <Number>3
         <Flats>1</Flats>
      </Number>
   </Street> 
   <Street>New street
      <Number>5
         <Flats>8</Flats>
      </Number>
   </Street> 
</Building>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why does this need to be xml and not a nosql database or something similar?

Comment: Your way of representing stuff in XML is a bit unusual - you're using "mixed content" - which is valid, but unusual. I would recommend using something like `<Street name="Wood Street" Number="3"> ..... </Street>` instead - that's much more common and easier to deal with, I believe...

Comment: @Jeff Mercado: it is valid XML - it's so called "mixed content" (mixed in terms of literal data as well as XML subnodes inside an XML element) - the most prominent example of that kind of XML would be XHTML documents.

Comment: @marc: Yeah, I wasn't familiar with that form.  But your comment cleared that up.

Answer (score 3):

You could represent this intuitively if you use LINQ to XML.  It will be a bit awkward however since it has mixed content.

e.g.,

```
var xmlStr = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<Building>
   <Street>Wood street
      <Number>3
         <Flats>1</Flats>
      </Number>
   </Street> 
</Building>
";
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlStr);
var newBuilding = new { Street = "Wood Street", Number = "5", Flats = 8 };

// See if the street exists
var street =
   (from e in doc.Element("Building").Elements("Street")
    let streetName = e.Nodes().OfType<XText>().Select(t => t.Value.Trim()).FirstOrDefault()
    where String.Equals(streetName, newBuilding.Street, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    select e).FirstOrDefault();

if (street != null) // street exists
{
    // add node to the current street
    var newNode =
        new XElement("Number",
            new XText(newBuilding.Number),
            new XElement("Flats", newBuilding.Flats));
    street.Add(newNode);
}
else // street does not exist
{
    // add node to the building list
    var newNode =
        new XElement("Street",
            new XText(newBuilding.Street),
            new XElement("Number",
                new XText(newBuilding.Number),
                new XElement("Flats", newBuilding.Flats)
            )
        );
    doc.Element("Building").Add(newNode);
}
```